# Laravel Localization not working as needed

Tags: php, laravel, routes, localization, laravel-blade

I have facing some problem in localization in laravel 5.4. I want my route prefix with localization.
here is my code

```
Route::prefix('{lang?}')->group(function($lang=NULL) {

    Route::get('/', 'LoginController@showLogin')->name('login');
});
```

If I hit route without giving any lang in url For example if I hit `localhost:8000` it shows this error[image: Error if no lang is provided]

But If I pass en in the url for example `localhost:8000/en` it shows the url[image]

I dont I understand what can I do in this situation. I google it but return without success. Please give me Suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You should create two different routes for optional language parameter:

```
Route::get('/', 'LoginController@showLogin')->name('login');
Route::get('/{lang}', 'LoginController@showLogin')->name('login');
```

Comment: My project has more than 50 routes. Will I have to add 50 more routes for this? Is it the more convenient way?